# Return rows in a multi-index df where it contains a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following multi-index df:

```
         pageid
sid vid
 1  ABC     dog
    ABC     cat
    ABC     fish
 2  DEF     pig
    DEF     cat
    DEF     fish
 3  GHI     pig
    GHI     cat
    GHI     dog
```

I want to keep sub-indexes that ONLY contain some value—in this example Ill use dog.

Before:

```
        pageid
sid vid
 1  ABC     dog
    ABC     cat
    ABC     fish
 2  DEF     pig
    DEF     cat
    DEF     fish
 3  GHI     pig
    GHI     cat
    GHI     dog
```

After (only `sid` that contain the `pageid` with value dog)

```
        pageid
sid vid
 1  ABC     dog
    ABC     cat
    ABC     fish
 3
    GHI     pig
    GHI     cat
    GHI     dog
```

Comment: Will you please add some code to actually create the sample dataframe in your question? It's hard to construct a dataframe based on only the text output, and it's even harder when you have multindexes like that. It would be super helpful.

Comment: `m=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],['ABC','ABC','ABC','DEF','DEF','DEF','GHI','GHI','GHI']],names=('sid','vid'));df=pd.DataFrame({'pageid':['dog','cat','fish','pig','cat','fish','pig','cat','dog']},index=m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```py
df.groupby('sid').filter(lambda x: x['pageid'].eq('dog').sum() > 0)
```

What that does it it:

1. Gets a list of sub-DFs, by their ID
2. Takes only those groups where the count of `pageid` in them is greater than `0`

Or as [@d.b suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917974/return-rows-in-a-multi-index-df-where-it-contains-a-specific-value/69918479?noredirect=1#comment123594913_69918479):

```py
df.loc[df['pageid'].eq('dog').groupby('sid').transform(any)]
```

What that does:

1. Creates a mask where each row is `True` if `pageId` is `dog`, `False` otherwise
2. Groups the masked rows by `sid`
3. Converts each group of masked rows to one masked row
4. Takes groups of rows from the dataframe using that mask